# MySql Foreign keys: ON DELETE NO ACTION behavour - how to leave info in referenced field?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables, one 'users' and one 'orders', where the order table has a foreign key reference to the user id table. (I'm using email address as user id in this case.)

What I want to accomplish is this:

1. If the user table id is updated (= email address is changed), this will reflect in the referenced order table user_id field. (This works fine using ON UPDATE CASCADE directive - no problem here!)
2. If the user is deleted from the user table, the order will remain, KEEPING the referenced user_id.

I'm having problem with the second goal:

If I use ON DELETE CASCADE on the referenced user id field, the order row is of course deleted.

If I use ON DELETE NO ACTION, I get an error when I try to remove the user. (#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails)

If I use ON DELETE SET NULL, I can delete the user row, but the referenced info is set to null so I can't track down who made that order...

Is there a way to allow removal of the user from the user table while keeping the referenced user_id information in the orders table?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Two options:

- Don't actually delete the user, just mark them as deleted by setting a `deleted` field.

or:

- Remove the foreign key constraint.

I would recommend the first option. Taking the second option can lead to data inconsistencies. Besides, just having the value of the key without the corresponding data in the other table will not help you much anyway.

Comment: Thank you, Mark! So, that means that it's not possible to achieve what I asked for in pure foreign key defintions..?

Comment: @Cambiata: That's right, it's not possible "in pure foreign key definitions". "Foreign key" *means* the value exists in another table. If you really delete the referenced row from the other table, you have to get rid of the foreign key value by a) deleting the entire row (ON DELETE CASCADE), or b) setting the FK value to NULL (ON DELETE SET NULL).

Comment: I see. I was hoping that NO ACTION alternatvie would mean, well... no action. In the meaning that the present value would remain untouched, behaving like a normal non-fk value. Obviously not! Thank you, Mark!

Comment: +1 for both the Q and A - I had the same idea about NO ACTION as @Cambiata. Btw, [MySQL docs further explain this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html); look for the part "In MySQL, equivalent to RESTRICT."

Comment: A disadvantage of using email as key and not really deleting records is that it prevents ex-customers from re-registering using the same email unless you add some form of de-deleting accounts, which does not instill confidence in people, because they expect their deleted account to be actually deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is another alternative - replace the user table's email address key with an autoincrement INT.

Then you could just copy the user attribute (ugh, denormalized) into the order (I guess you could justify it as being the 'email address of the ordering user at the time of order').

Then ON DELETE SET NULL could reset the foreign key INT but not the copied attribute (email address).