# Hibernate Foreign key voilation [Need help understanding]

Tags: java, hibernate

Apologies that I was not able to understand the error and so don't have any solutions that I can think of. I do understand that this is a foreign key error which happens when I am trying to delete some entities, those have a many to many join and I was not able to pin point where I am getting it wrong.

I am working with Hibernate = 3.6, the error I get is as below:

```
  [testng] 23:01:11.050 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Batch entry 0 delete from tablename1 where id=1 was aborted: ERROR: update or delete on table "tablename1" violates foreign key constraint "tablename2_id_fkey" on table "tablename2"
   [testng]   Detail: Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "tablename2".  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
   [testng] org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
   [testng]     at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
   [testng]     at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
   [testng]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
   [testng]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
   [testng]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:189)
   [testng]     at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
   [testng]     at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
   [testng]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
   [testng]     at mypackage.closeSession(GenericDao.java:62)
   [testng]     at mypackage.deleteIntegEntities(GenericDao.java:57)
```

My error happens in the session.flush() in the closeSession method, Also adding my get and delete methods below:

```
 public List<T> getXEntities()
    {
        return session.createCriteria(classType)
                .add(Restrictions.ilike(FieldName, "X", MatchMode.START))
                .list();
    }

    public void deleteXEntities()
    {
        openSession();

        getXEntities()
                .stream()
                .forEach(e -> session.delete(e));

        closeSession();
    }

    public void closeSession()
    {
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
```

Also, my entities are defines as:
**Entity1**

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"policies"})
@Entity
@Table(name = "tablename3")
@SuppressFBWarnings(value = {"EI_EXPOSE_REP", "EI_EXPOSE_REP2"})
public class tablename3 implements Serializable
{
    @Column(name = "idx")
    @Id
    private String idx;

    @ManyToMany(
            targetEntity = tablename1.class,
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "tablename2",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idx"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pid")
    )
    private Set<Policy> policies;
}
```

**Entity 2 is**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tablename1")
public class tablename1 implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "pid")
    private int policyId;
}
```

(Other non relevant columns are ommited)
tablename1 has columns - idx, pid
tablename2 has columns - idx
tablename3 has columns - idx, pid

It occurs to me that with the entities above, tablename3 and tablename1 are joined over tablename2. But I am not able to figure out why the deleteX method fails. I believe it is not cascading the delete change, but I am not able to pinpoint it.

I understand that this is all over the place, but put forward the best I could collect. Any help or direction to work on would help.

Comment: the error message says "ERROR: update or delete on table "tablename1" violates foreign key constraint "tablename2_id_fkey" on table "tablename2"" and " Detail: Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "tablename2"" where is your tablename2?

Comment: @Icarus The table is defined as part of a separate package. This package only holds testing part so we have just entities- tablename1 and tablename3 defined. tablename2 is picked up from the DB as part of the join.

Comment: the error message tells you that the key is being referenced in tablename2. you should try deleting the row making the reference first

Comment: @lcarus , trying to understand if I am right here. 
So, I believe setting up the cascade option in the entities (as I have above), handles deleting references, right?  I don't see any other way to do it, apart from manually repeating delete over all the tables involved. 

Also, the tables are defined in SQL, where - Foreign keys are set with ON DELETE NO ACTION, example: 

```
 CONSTRAINT tablename2_fkey FOREIGN KEY (policy_id)
      REFERENCES tablename1 (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

Comment: As per - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511485/mysql-foreign-keys-on-delete-no-action-behavour-how-to-leave-info-in-referenc ; that could be a reason of the foreign key error? I don't have control on the database, so can't experiment that.

Comment: I am working with AWS RDS